# Php CSV export UTF8 encoding causing incorrect excel format

Tags: php, excel, csv, utf-8

i tired doing an csv export. I needed two languages (tamil and english) in the sheet using normal headers

```
    $now = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s");
    header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
    header("Last-Modified: {$now} GMT");
    header ( 'Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel') ;
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    echo $content;
```

This was causing problems in the tamil characters being displayed. But the format of the excel was fine. So i used a UTF8 encoding to display the tamil characters as shown below.

```
    $now = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s");
    header('Pragma: public');
    header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header("Last-Modified: {$now} GMT");
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    echo chr(255) . chr(254) . mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
```

This helped with the characters and both languages are being displayed fine now but the format of the csv being generated is disrupted. Everything is being displayed in a single column. Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: I think  $content contain entire row,is right ?

Comment: Yup. The whole content (all rows)

Comment: try encoding apply on field level,then all thing work correct,because when use apply encoding on  $content it's  encoded csv separator so all contain display one column

Comment: Then do we want to declare the headers over the encoding step ...?

Comment: can you post your code,how you prepare $content

Comment: Please try `echo chr(239) . chr(187) . chr(191) . $content;`.

Comment: @AxelRichter.. Still the same result. :(

Comment: Was a try. Normally `Excel` can open `CSV`-files which are `UTF-8` encoded if they have a `UTF-8`-`BOM`.